# GRUB2 won't Mount encrypted partitions for Kali 2019.4

Tags: mount, kali-linux, grub2, luks, disk-encryption

While attempting to boot a new installation of Kali Linux 2019.4 on a USB drive it appears GRUB 2.04-5 will not decrypt the root partition:

```
Volume group "cryotic" not found
Cannot process volume group cryotic
```

Cryotic is the Logical Volume group contained in the encrypted partition - it holds three Logical Volumes (/root,/home,swap).

I have attempted to decrypt the partition directly in the GRUB interface of the Live USB disk I used to create this installation. I tried things such as `insmod luks`, `insmod cryptodisk`, `insmod crypto`, followed by `cryptomount -a` but the partition is not mounted, nor am I asked for a password to decrypt it.

Is there a procedure I am missing that can decrypt it? I don't believe I can reconfigure GRUB with grub-install without having first booted into the OS?

The basic partition scheme of the drive is:

```
1: ESP 536 MB (FAT32)  
2: /boot 256 MB (ext2)  
3: encrypted  
    criotic volume group   
    a: /     16 GB (ext4) LV   
    b: /home 10 GB (ext4) LV   
    c: swap ~4GB LV
```

Comment: cryptsetup luksDump, if it's LUKS2 then it's because grub still only supports luks1

Comment: It is indeed version 2. I am going to attempt to use luks1 by way of the shell in the installation menu.

Answer (score 1):

Kali linux's installation encryption manager installs luks2 by default, but GRUB2 only supports luks1.

Start the installation as normal and then use the shell from the installation menu to setup encryption with `cryptsetup` using the option `--type luks1`. You can also setup the logical volumes in the shell with the various lvm commands. Once returned to the installation process assign / and /home to their logical partitions.

To allow the boot-loader to discover the encrypted root partition setup /etc/crypttab.